# Meaning of the verb "front" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context, slang

It's from the sixth episode of the first season of *Breaking Bad*. The context is one guys took another guy to a drug distributor to sell him drugs. The guy hands him a pack of meth, but the drug dealer refuses to give him money.

> Guy A: You said this was cool, okay! Money for meth, cash upfont.
>
> Guy B: Don't **front**, dude! Tuco's good for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To front is slang meaning to make pretense, to cop an attitude, or to get too upset inappropriately.

In other words...

> *Don’t get upset. You know* Tuco is good for it. *He will pay you back. He is worthy of a little credit.*